# separate moodle landing page from interior frontpage

Tags: moodle

I am working on a Moodle site and need to create a marketing landing page. I am using the frontpage.php file called into action by this code in the config.php file:

```
// The site home page.
    'frontpage' => array(
        'file' => 'frontpage.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-pre',
        'options' => array('nonavbar' => true),
    ),
```

Is there a way to call a different file when logged into the system?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to call a different page because the Moodle front page is effectively just a special course instance (with course id = 1).

What you can do, however, is change its layout and overall appearance by modifying the layout files and CSS styles for the applied theme (located at theme/{themename}/layout/ and theme/{themename}/style/ respectively).

A good place to start would be to install a theme that is configurable via the Moodle admin interface, the best example of which is probably the Essential theme (https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=theme_essential or https://github.com/DBezemer/moodle-theme_essential for the GitHub repo). This theme provides home page marketing spots, a slide show and a bunch of other stuff straight out of the box, so you may well find that it does everything you need and you can avoid having to mess with the code at all.

Hope this helps.

Tony

Comment: Thanks for the response @tony. I have a good grip on the code just not totally familiar with what Moodle can and can't do. I will just use a subdomain for the Moodle instance and build out the marketing page in a separate independent space.